# Reverse Polish Notation Quadratic formula

Tags: notation, quadratics

The quadratic formula is $$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

I tried converting this to RPN; I am new to doing this, and I have thus: `b-ac*4*-b2^+±a2*/`. Am I correct?

## Edit 1: Forgot the radical.

`b-ac*4*-b2^+√±a2/`

Comment: Interesting exercise.  I don't see how the square root is incorporated in the RPN expression, and there are a couple of technicalities to be ironed out with minus-as-unary operator and plus-or-minus as binary operator.

Comment: You should distinguish _minus_ from _negation_ (they certainly aren't the same key on the calculator).

Comment: @hardmath ah! I forgot about that.

Comment: @Jared how might I do that? They're the same key on the keyboard :/

Comment: Also there is _not_ a unique way to write this in RPN.  It appears that you are trying to right it "left-to-right"--which may not be the best way (and if the expression is complicated enough the calculator will _not_ always properly calculate the result because it has a limited stack).

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ That's odd, they aren't on my HP calculator (there's a `-` key and a `+/-` key).  And it makes no sense how they could possibly be the same button.

Comment: @Jared excuse me, on the _computer_ keyboard. I am to print out as such.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Doesn't matter--you still need to distinguish the two operations--I assure you the computer distinguishes them, even if you hit the same key when typing it into plain text (recall that the computer doesn't interpret plain text).

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ However, it does appear that your expression is "correct" (although not the order I would have written it as).

Comment: @Jared Thanks! I'll just say that I will only use the `-` sign as the unary negation sign (as `a b - = a b - +`, the former `-` being binary and the latter being unary).

Comment: Try to think of formula as a tree, where vertices are operations and children are operands, where the root is "the expression" itself. Try $a+b*c$, for instance. Then "Left\_Subtree - Right\_subtree - Operation" order walk would be the result. @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ it's like $b,b,*,a,c,*,4,*,-,$\\sqrt,unary$\pm,b,-,2,a,*,/$ the result then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since someone brought up a tree, I'll add an answer, which is less of an answer and more of a discussion.  If I was trying to write this from "left-to-right" (which I cannot and will not try to define), I would probably do the following (things inside parenthesis are functions):

`b(neg)b2(y^x)4ac**-√(+/-)2a*/`

Which gives the following tree:

[image]

Another way could be to start inside the square root:

`b2(y^x)4a*c*-√b(neg)(+/-)2a*/`

Which gives the following (equivalent) tree:

[image]

And a slightly *different* tree could be:

[image]

I would argue that the last tree is probably the "best" (even though they are all equivalent)...think in terms of the how large the stack needs to be in each case.

**p.s. The $\pm$ needs different meanings, but I'm trying to compactly represent two different calculations--the $+$ is fine in the last two cases, but the $-$ requires a negation and then an add (in the last two cases)--this is because addition is commutative but subtraction *is not*.**

Comment: How did you make those trees?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Probably not the easiest possible way, but I use [Ipe](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/) and then I export it as a .png file and added the picture to my answer.  The reason I use Ipe is because it produces [vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) (specifically .eps and .pdf formats) _and_ it supports latex.

Comment: Ahh sweet! Thanks for the input.